# Do we need to allow 6 tags?

Tags: discussion

For hand histories, I think the following tags apply:

1. Poker variant (texas-hold-em, omaha, 7-card-stud)
2. Betting structure (limit, no-limit, pot-limit)
3. live or online
4. cash-game or tournament
5. Stakes (1-2nl)
6. hand-history

Some of the information is duplicate (no-limit and 1-2nl), but which do we cut?

I suppose a related question would be how much information we plan to cram into a tag?

texas-hold-em + no-limit => nlhe
no-limit + stakes => 1-2nl
1-2nlhe?

It will be very hard to follow tags nicely if we go to that level of granularity.

Comment: This has been [requested](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/13912/158779) before and declined without comment.  However, that was before Stack Exchange was what it is now, and that user did not try to address specific reasons as you did.

Comment: In #1 I believe the variant should just say "hold-em".

Comment: That's fine if we have a texas-hold-em synonym.  New users that start typing texas should have the correct tag suggested.

Comment: If you add a tag to the body of the description below the question and not as a direct tag, does it show up in the filter system? If so, and 5 tags aren't enough, then adding a tag into the body to replace a relevant word would be a way of using additional tags. That said, I used it a couple of times just to experiment and it slightly detracts from readability IMO.

Comment: MSE: [Why is there a tag limit?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34732/why-is-there-a-tag-limit)

Answer (score 2):

We need to figure this out; whether by more tags or better use of tags.

#### I'd like more tags if possible.

Barring that, I suggest #1 and #2 can often be combined.  "NLHE" and "PLO8" are examples of common abbreviations that combine the two concepts.  Additionally, one probably isn't intereted in finding questions about pot-limit specifically but rather as it pertains to Omaha, etc.

However, I think this comes with the heavy cost of making tags like "texas-hold-em" less useful.